# MySQL ODBC error "server has gone away"

Tags: mysql, iis, asp-classic, odbc, ado

Occasionally we're seeing an error from ASP pages:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][MyODBC 5.00.11][MySQL] 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

We're handling it the best way we can in ASP but it still crops up. I think it's more to do with the MySQL ODBC driver than the ASP code. We never see this with PHP code we also have running under the same IIS server, however PHP re-connects each time it is ran, whereas I believe the ODBC driver connects once and stays connected.

I've checked the settings in the driver but there doesn't seem to be anything I can change to help mitigate the problem.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to reduce the number of times it happens?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the connection is timing out. This is not a setting that you can change at the ODBC level. I got round it by polling the connection every 10 seconds with a simple query. That keeps the connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about ASP, but in Java/Tomcat/DBCP we have ability to stick a simple test statement (such as `SELECT 1`) in connection pools before actually getting the connection. Maybe there is something similar in ASP, too?